# Iterate through one letter each click

Tags: java

I'm clueless at the moment how would I Iterate through one letter in a word each click

for example the word is `"DOG"`

When someone clicks a button for example named `"Click me"`

It would give them a option to change the color of the first letter to the last
If the player clicks RED the first Letter D would be red if the player clicks on GREEN the second letter O would be green and if someone clicks on purple the last letter G would be purple.

How would I get the next letter in a word?

Comment: You maintain an index value with the "current" letter position.

Comment: String str = "testString";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Every call of nextClick() give you the next letter (as a String):

```
String word = "DOG";
int position = 0;

public String nextClick() {
    if (word != null && position < word.length()) {
        position++;
        return word.substring(position-1, position);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int pos = 0;
String word = ....

public char nextLetter() {
     if (pos < word.length()) {
         return word.charAt(pos++);
     }
     return ''; // returns empty char
 }
```

If you want to cycle when reaching the end of the String then do:

```
public char nextLetter() {
     char c = word.charAt(pos);
     pos = (pos + 1) ℅ word.length();
     return c;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replying to your
*Question: How would I get the next letter in a word*

Assign your word to `String` and convert `String` to `char` array and then just iterate the array.Like in your example on each click you need to pull next element from array.

```
String str = "DOG";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```